# How to change the status on modal confirm alert ok button in codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I have setup modal alert to change status but status become changed automatically when open modal alert only. How do I change the status only when click on `ok` button of modal?

**My controller**

```
public function Changetobilledstatus()
{
    $id=$this->input->post('value');

    $data=array('Rental_status'=>3);
    $this->General_model->update($this->table,$data,'RA_id',$id);
    echo json_encode($data);     

}
```

**My html**

```
<div id="UnbilledModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Do You Need update status into billed ?</h4></div>


    <div class="modal-footer">


    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary option">OK</button>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**My script**

```
$('td', row).eq(10).html('<center><select id="Rental_status" onchange="changeStatus('+data['RA_id']+')"><option value="1">Select</option><option value="2">Billed</option></select></center>');
function changeStatus(RA_id){

var val=$("#Rental_status").val();
var id= RA_id;
if(RA_id){
$.ajax({
              url:"<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/Rental_agreement/Changetobilledstatus",
              type: 'POST',
              data: {value:RA_id},
              dataType: 'json',
              success:
              function(data)//quotation_status
              {
                //location.reload();
                //alert(data['quantity']);
                $('#UnbilledModal').modal();

              },
              error:function(e){
              console.log("error");
              }

      });
}
}
```

Comment: What status? What is changed automatically?

Comment: I need to update rental status field into 3 only when click on modal ok button

Comment: Ok, but then why use a select box? If you are going to have 1 option which is "billed" why make the user select from a dropdown? Just have the modal open on click. If user hits ok then it changes the status. Simpler, and better ux.

Answer (score 0):

=> your HTML CODE

```
$('td', row).eq(10).html('<center><select id="Rental_status" onchange="changeStatus('+data['RA_id']+')"><option value="1">Select</option><option value="2">Billed</option></select></center>');
```

// in select you have to write code in this manner

```
'<a title="Change Status" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-user="' + id + '" data-status="' + data + '" href="#UnbilledModal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="change_status(this)">Disable</a>'



<div id="UnbilledModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                <?php echo form_open('your url', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'name' => 'your form name')); ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" /> //fetch id and status
                <input type="hidden" name="status" />
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Do You Need update status into billed ?</h4></div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary option">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

=> your Javascript Code

```
function change_status(obj) {
        var id = $(obj).data('id');         
        var status = $(obj).data('status'); // here you can fetch data value 

        $('input[name="id"]').val(id);
        $('input[name="status"]').val(status);// use in modal right
    }

    function show_modal(obj) {
        var modal_id = $(obj).attr('href');
        var content = $(modal_id).children('div.modal-dialog').children('div.modal-content');
        var data_url = $(obj).attr('data-url');
        $.ajax({
            url: data_url,
            dataType: "html",
            catch : false,
            success: function (data) {
                $(content).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: how is "show_modal" called? don't see any reference to it

Comment: this is just reference my friend.
You can use only change_status function my ref <a></a> link and modal thats it